# Start app automatically on system boot in RN

Tags: react-native

I would like to know if there is a way to start an app at the device startup in React Native.
My app, when manually opened, calls an API for local push notification, so I would like to let the app start itself automatically as for example Whatsapp or Facebook works.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS there is no way to tell the system to start an application on device start. You will have to wait for the user to run the app the first time in order to push the local notification.

Comment: It is not true at 100%. In fact if you set that your app has VoIP service, the app will start as service at startup, but obviously the app has to have VoIP service running as Skype, for example.

Comment: There is no way to trigger an app to start or schedule a local push notification when it is in the background on iOS.